# LINQ to SQL Problem with table named 'System'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the unfortunate problem that a database I'm trying to use with LINQ to SQL has a table in it named 'System'. The side-effect of this is that there are HUGE namespace conflicts once the .dbml has been generated.

Renaming the table is not an option.

Any ideas you might have would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a _ before or after the name in the dbml file

Comment: Actually, this is what I ended up doing, and it was by far the easiest solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem had the same problem myself :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option would be renaming the table in the Designer/mapping, even though you can't rename it in the DB.

Comment: Thank you. I was afraid of that. It's just a lot of manual effort going through the DBML changing table-mapping names. I was trying to avoid that. Oh well, guess I'll get started...

Answer (score 1):

I generally construct my own Linq to Sql classes instead of using the .dbml files. A naming convention I use is TableName + "Dto". Dto standing for Data Transfer Object. If rolling your own Dto classes is not an option, you can simply go into the designer edit the name of your System table dbml to SystemDto. It will still map correctly to the database object, and yet you will have no name conflicts. If you're interested in seeing some hand rolled dto's let me know :). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

you have to disable the "Pluralize New Objects" feature.

Have a look at:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/29/linq-to-sql-part-2-defining-our-data-model-classes.aspx

An easier and better way is just add a Namespace to the context. Right click on the Linq to SQL designer --> property --> ContextNameSpace

Comment: Adding the namespace was easy and fixed the problem. Thank you.